# Erroneous Gitkraken installation by means of Yaourt Manajro

Tags: linux, github, gitkraken, manjaro

My operating system is Manjaro Linux with gnome Desktop.

I installed gitkraken with yaourt, whereas I was asked to install `libcurl-openssh` for gitkraken. 
Nevertheless, I have gitkraken installed now!

But when I go to the file/folder browser dialog in gitkraken, I see a broken fonts in the dialog as you can see on the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJNZW.png)

**How can I fix the wrong fonts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known problem, see:

- https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gitkraken/?comments=all
- https://github.com/Azd325/gitkraken/issues/45

It's because gitkraken uses an old electron version